# looking for a slight variant of GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I have a table like so:

```
id attr
1  A
2  A
3  C
4  C
5  D
6  F
```

I want a count of all the A's B's (but not the C's D's, etc..)  Note that my table has zero B's.

So I want a command like this:

```
SELECT count(attr=A, attr=B) FROM table;
```

or this:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table GROUP_BY attr IN (A, B);
```

and get:

```
attr count
A    2
B    0
```

My actual table has about a thousand `attr`s.  I want to do a group_by-ish thing on maybe a hundred or so of them.  It's important that i get the count of zero for certain attrs and that i can correlate the attr to the count.

I know this is a basic question and I'm not surprised if this has been asked before.  I searched..  But my apologies anyway..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT T.attr,
       COUNT(Y.id)
FROM   (SELECT 'A' AS attr
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'B') AS T
       LEFT JOIN YourTable Y
         ON Y.attr = T.attr
GROUP  BY T.attr
```

Comment: To extend this to 100 attrs, do I need 99 UNION ALL statements?  Do you know, off the top of your head, if this should have similar performance to GROUP BY?

Comment: @Paul - Do you have another table which contains all attributes you can outer join on? e.g. `SELECT A.attr,COUNT(Y.id) FROM  Attributes A LEFT JOIN YourTable Y ON Y.attr = A.attr WHERE A.attr IN ('A','B') GROUP  BY A.attr`

Comment: No I do not.  I do not have authority to create one either.

Comment: That's a shame! I only dabble in MySQL so not sure if there are any particular performance implications with the `UNION ALL` approach.

Comment: I've done union all with quite a few values (at least 100), and I have to say that the performance isn't quite that bad.  One question though, if there is no list of attributes how are you constructing the union query? Does it all just exist as code?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
SELECT T.Attr,Count(A.ID)
FROM (
SELECT CONVERT('A',char) AS Attr
UNION 
SELECT CONVERT('B',char)  AS Attr
) AS T
LEFT JOIN MyTable AS A
ON T.Attr=MyTable.Attr
GROUP BY T.Attr
ORDER BY T.Attr;
```

The Convert part may not be necessary but was necessary in my testing.